# Alterar de javascript para jquery a linha de codigo 2

Tags: jquery

Como posso selecionar o elemento numero 2 usando jquery? Estou selecionando com javascript mas gostaria de usar Jquery.

```
34m
1- var hiddenFieldName = ‘UIHiddenFieldSubjectValidaty’ + jQuery("#UIDropDownListValidity option:selected").val(); vai buscar valor do id da select

2-var newSubjectText = document.getElementById(hiddenFieldName).value;
vai buscar os valores da select…

3-jQuery("#UITextBoxSubject").val(newSubjectText);
coloca os valor da select na textbox
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: var newSubjectText = $('#hiddenFieldName').val();

Comment: Fiz assim , tambem deu erro na mesma.

Comment: Tambem fiz, assim, sempre a dar erro, como vou buscar id no select, depois pego no valor do id. com javascript funciona, mas jquery dá sempre error, já exprimentei dessa, forma.....

Comment: Cara, o valor já está salvo na variável, apenas faça assim: `var newSubjectText = hiddenFieldName`;

Comment: var hiddenFieldName contem este valor = UIHiddenFieldSubjectValidaty360.  quando faço getElement contem este valor = NOS Follow Car + posição partilha durante os próximos 15 minutos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa selecionar o elemento desse jeito, ao invés de selecionar dessa maneira, use o seletor `id = #` e passe o nome do elemento, assim:

```
var newSubjectText = $('#hiddenFieldName').val();
```

Um exemplo se fosse com o seletor de `classe = .`

```
var newSubjectText = $('.hiddenFieldName').val();
```

Nesse seu exemplo, você está tentando capturar o valor de um elemento que não existe, o mesmo já está salvo na variável `hiddenFieldName`, não precisa capturar o valor novamente.